# Identifying the orientation bundle uniquely

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology

A nonorientable surface $S$ is homeomorphic to the $k$-th connected sum 
$\mathbb{R}P^2 \sharp  \ldots  \sharp \mathbb{R}P^2$.

For each nonorientable surface $S$ there exists an oriented $2$-fold covering $\tilde S$, the covering bundle. This is isomorphic to the determinant bundle.

Now the number of $2$-fold coverings on $S$ can be computed with the help of $H^1(S;\mathbb{Z}/2)$, that is $2^k$.

The question is: is there a possibility to identify the orientation bundle $\tilde S$ within the set of all $2$-fold coverings on $S$ uniquely.

It is clear that it has to be oriented and connected.

Or another question is, if there is a surface $X$ given. Is it possible to find out if it is the orientation bundle $\tilde S$.

Comment: This is not a question: you have a construction of a particular 2-fold covering space as the orientation cover (= sphere bundle of determinant bundle), and want to know whether it identifies a unique double cover. Of course it does, it is a construction.

Comment: I think my question was not precise. In fact, I was asking for the complex structure. The topological classification is clear as you all pointed out.

Comment: It's not at all clear to me that "the complex structure" makes sense.  There are many complex structures on a compact, orientable surface.  How would you associate one such structure to a surface, just based on the fact that it double covers something non-orientable?  What would you like this structure to satisfy?

Comment: You are right, so perhaps a better question is the following. Let there be a given surface $X$. Is there some method to find out if it is the orientation covering of some nonorientable surface?

Comment: Yes, if it admits an orientation-reversing involution.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you please tell me the argument for this. So why is it the orientation-reversing involution?

Answer (score 6):

If I interpret your question correctly, you are asking which class in $H^1(S; \mathbb{Z}/2 \mathbb{Z})$ corresponds to the orientation covering. This is the first Stiefel-Whitney class of $TS$, and there are [many constructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stiefel%25E2%2580%2593Whitney_class) for it.

Comment: Maybe the simplest way to think about this class is in terms of the universal coefficient theorem, which tells you that this class is really just a map from $H_1(S; Z)$ to $Z/2Z$.  As $H_1$ is the abelianization of the fundamental group, this function can be thought of as the answer to a yes/no question, asked about loops $\gamma$ in $S$.  That question is: is the tangent bundle orientable when restricted to $\gamma$?  

Answer (score 1):

Any connected orientable surface $X$ which doubly covers $S$ must be homeomorphic to the orientation cover $\tilde{S}$.

Proof: Connected orientable surfaces are classified up to homeomorphism by their Euler characteristic. Since the Euler characteristic is multiplicative,

$$\chi(X)=\chi(\tilde{S})=2\cdot\chi(S).$$

Comment: I guess it is implied, but it may be worth to note that yet, the covering may well NOT be the orientation covering.

Comment: Hmm yes. Can you think of an example?

Comment: An orientable double cover $X \to S$ lifts to a map $X \to \tilde{S}$ by the universal property of the orientation cover. This map is a continuous bijection, and so a homeomorphism as both source and target and compact Hausdorff.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a slightly different perspective.  Double coverings are classified by subgroups of index two in the fundamental group.  So it makes sense to ask for a description of the index two subgroup corresponding to the orientation double cover.  This subgroup consists of loops is $S$ that lift to loops in the orientation double cover, and hence these are exactly those loops along which the tangent bundle of $S$ is orientable.  This is of course closely related to the comment I made on Andrea's answer.